# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel's Datetime? gives: Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, runtime, verificationexception

Well, the title sums it up it pretty well, **I do know that I should be providing enough information to make this as easy as possible to answer, but I got absolutelly no idea of what may be causing this all I know is how it happends.**

My shot here is to find someone who had this problem in the same or similar cincurstances.

**Scenario:**
I've got a view model class and everything works perfectly, but there's a Datetime property that gives me that default value for Datetime (01/01/0001), so I made it Nullable and then I got this error.

I know there are a lot of different ways to achieve what I intended by making it nullable, but I'm worried that if I don't find out what the problem is or what's causing it, it may happen again later on something more complex and important or even worse, something that I don't have a plan B for.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated, also if there's something else you want me to include in the question, just let me know and I'll edit it right away, I Honestly don't know what would matter to show in this particular case.

Thanks!

Comment: How is that property being used? At what point do you get the error? When the view first renders, when it posts back to the server, etc. A bit more info around how the viewmodel is used would be helpful

Comment: I've just managed to find out where it occurs, we've got an expression tree that converts a query result into to a View-Model and that is where the problem lies, I don't understand it enough to fix the expression but I do know it's coming from there, I'll try to get the person who made the expression in the first place, that way I might find out the root of the problem and answer my own question in case anyone needs it in the future. Thanks Levelnis

Comment: Or you could post it here? Sure someone could help

Comment: @BrenoSarkis: Did you solved this issue?